# Relation between independent/dependent variable for substitution in ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, chain-rule

I have the following ODE:
$$
y'=y^2\cos t-\frac{1}{10}y
$$
substituting $z=1/y$, I understand this is $z(t)=1/y(t)$. I know $t$ is the independent variable and $y$ is dependent variable.

What is the role of $z$ here? Does it change the dependent variable when $y(t)=1/z(t)$?

I saw in the book that it is written:
$$
y'=\frac{-z'}{z^2}
$$
does this mean that:
$$
y'(t)=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}
$$
is the relation $z(y(t))$?

Can someone explain the implicit differentiation in this expression? What are the dependent and independent variables here?

I understand how to finish this, but I want to know the intuition behind. I always confuse what are the dependent and independent variables when doing substitution, and to what variable I need to implicitly differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'$ in your equation means $ \frac {dy}{dt}$ since z is a func tion of the variable t

$$y'=\frac {dy}{dt}$$
$$y'=\frac {dy}{dz}\frac {dz}{dt}=\frac {dy}{dz}z'$$
Since you have $y=\frac 1 z$ then
$$\frac {dy}{dz}=\frac {d}{dz}\frac 1z=-\frac {1}{z^2}$$
Therefore,
$$y'=\frac {dy}{dz}z'=-\frac {z'}{z^2}$$
The simpliest way is to differentiate with respect to the variable t

$$y=\frac 1 z$$
Where z is a function of t 
$$\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac d {dt}\left(\frac 1 z\right)$$
$$y'=\frac  {-z'}{z^2}$$

Comment: thankyou so much!!!! , is the relation become $y(z(t))$? and is this change the dependent variable from y to z?

Comment: well $y(z(t))$ means $y(t)$ since z is a function of t too

Comment: thanks!!, so the ide using substitution here is to change all $y$ to $z$ right? so in order to do that I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $z$ so I can substitute it to the original equation?

Comment: Yes exactly we substitute y with z so we can solve more easily the equation... I see why you are a bit confused...but here the substitution is$y=1/z$ without the variable t but we could have in another equation $y=z+3t$ as a substitution..on the other hand stating $y(z)$ maybe ambiguous when $z=z(t)$ it may means that z is a variable and y a function of z

Comment: Note that this equation you posted can be solved without any substitution...and its' very easy to integrate it directly  @vik

Comment: thanks, but in this problem both z and y is a function of t right? how can you integrate directly? i mean how to separate y and x there without substitution.. i think it is a bit hard

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form
$$-\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)^2}-\frac{1}{10y(t)}=-\cos(t)$$
substituting $$u(t)=\frac{1}{y(t)}$$
then you will get
$$u'(t)-\frac{u(t)}{10}=-\cos(t)$$
can you finish?

Comment: thanks,  I understand how to finish this. but I want to know the intuition behind this. I always confuse when doing substitution, what is the dependent and independent variable, and to what variable I need to implicitly differentiate. when you substitute $y=1/z$  so $y'=\frac{-z'}{z^2}$, I want to know is this the relation ? $y(t)'=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: i would say this is the Quotient and the chain rule